How to disable/enable reactive form using signals
I want to disable/enable a formGroup, based on a signal input. I do not want to use [disabled] to toggle the form.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="test"/>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  disableForm = input(false);
  name = 'Angular';
  form = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl(1),
  });

  ngOnInit() {}
}

Parent passes in the input like below.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child [disableForm]="disableForm()"/>
    <button (click)="toggleDisabled()">toggle disable</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  disableForm = signal(false);

  toggleDisabled() {
    this.disableForm.update((value: boolean) => !value);
  }
}

Looking for a method that triggers/reacts based on the change of the signal.

This can be done with input signal, basically we use effect to perform the logic when the signal changes, based on that we enable and disable the form using disableForm or enableForm.
disableForm = input(false);
...

...
constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    if (this.disableForm()) {
      this.form.disable();
    } else {
      this.form.enable();
    }
  });
}

Then on button press, we toggle the signal using update method, inside the update, we get the previous value and the returned value will be updated as the new value.
disableForm = signal(false);

toggleDisabled() {
  this.disableForm.update((value: boolean) => !value);
}

The signal, can be passed as input to the child component.
<app-child [disableForm]="disableForm()"/>
<button (click)="toggleDisabled()">toggle disable</button>

Full Code:
import { Component, effect, input, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="test"/>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  disableForm = input(false);
  name = 'Angular';
  form = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl(1),
  });

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.disableForm()) {
        this.form.disable();
      } else {
        this.form.enable();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Child],
  template: `
    <app-child [disableForm]="disableForm()"/>
    <button (click)="toggleDisabled()">toggle disable</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  disableForm = signal(false);

  toggleDisabled() {
    this.disableForm.update((value: boolean) => !value);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

If you want to disable the form then you can simply disable whole from group like this.form.disable(); this.
You need to do this on input single change which you have assigned to disableForm variable in Child component.
You can enable or disable formGroup on input signal change.
input signal change can be detected by two things effect and computed. But basically computed is used to automatically update the value on input signal change and effect is used to automatically react input signal change.
please check angular official documentation for effect: https://angular.dev/guide/signals#effects
in your case you can use effect.
effect(() => {
  if (this.disableForm()) {
    this.form.disable();
  } else {
    this.form.enable();
  }
});

also, you can use computed in similar manner.
computed(() => {
   if (this.disableForm()) {
       this.form.disable();
   } else {
       this.form.enable();
   }
});

Also there is one another alternative to detect input signal change though RxJS (using Observable) like below:
toObservable(this.disableForm).subscribe(isDisabled => {
   if (isDisabled) {
      this.form.disable(); 
   } else {
      this.form.enable();
   }
 });

